# react-native filter and search data in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, react-native, filtering

I am new with react-native. Now I am using react-native for my school Assignment.
Before using react-native, I used ionic.

I am trying to filter data. The data is in JSON Format.
Does react-native have a filter like ionic?

Ref: [Angular Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes, i've searched by google. but i need plugin or sth else.
so i can filter dynamically and using to another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Ionic directive `filter` also do filter logic before `for loop`. so you can do it yourself before render.

use ES6 filter function or other utils.

e.g. show odd number

```
render() {
    return(
        <View>
            {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                .filter(value => value % 2 === 1)
                .map(value => (<Text key={value}>{value}</Text>))}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Go a step further, you can create a component with filter property, and implement custom logic. then you can use it like Ionic.

e.g.

```
class FilterNumbers extends Component {

static propTypes = {
    numbers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    filter: PropTypes.func,
};

static defaultProps = {
    filter: null,
    numbers: [],
};

render() {
    var filteredNumbers = this.props.numbers;
    if (this.props.filter) {
        filteredNumbers = this.props.numbers.filter(this.props.filter);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            {filteredNumbers.map(value => (<Text key={value}>{value}</Text>))}
        </View>);
};
```

}

use it

```
<FilterNumbers numbers={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]} filter={value => value % 2 === 1}/>
```

P.S.

- I use Array with number for simple demo. You can use Array with JSON and adjustment logic to fit it.
- It is best to use [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) to display iterable data.